# Samsung Galaxy S4 play edition and exFat

Tags: google-play-store, external-sd, file-system, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Does the Play version of the Galaxy s4 include support for exFat in the sdcard reader? Or is exFat support one of the extras that Samsung adds to the device (presumably since they made the licencing agreement with MS)?

This question is specifically about the version available from Google's Play store that comes unlocked and without touchwiz.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume YES.

From [allaboutgalaxys4](http://allaboutgalaxys4.com/galaxy-s4-online-manual/inserting-a-memory-card/):

> The device supports the FAT and the exFAT file systems for memory
>   cards. When inserting a card formatted in a different file system, the
>   device asks to reformat the memory card.

Comment: That link doesn't mention if the exfat feature is also available on the Play edition.